# Hide the border line using CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, opacity

I am making a section which contains price info section and order now button.

Here, there is a wrapper `border` class that make the border for the entire section.

**Scenario**:

In this case consider that button is disabled with opacity and hence it looks like this now.

```css
.border {
   border: 4px solid rgb(195, 0, 38);
   border-bottom: transparent;
}

.info-card {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(195, 0, 38);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.order-button {
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
<div class="info-card">
  <h1> Info Section </h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="order-button">
   <button>
      Order Now
   </button>
</div>
```

But the requirement is that the border line should go behind the button (and not above the button) as like the below image.

Expected Result:

[image]

**Note:** Here opacity is included to make the button look like disabled.

Also the color given above varies and so please don't include any other addition of colors.

Tried with increasing z-index of button but that doesn't work in this case.

Comment: The bottom border (if not replaced by a transparent one) already _is_ behind your button. But of course it will shine through, if you give the button opacity. You can't have it both ways - "behind, but not shining through", _and_ "button will have opacity", that simply can't work. Nothing a z-index can do for you in that regard either. Use something else to make the button "look disabled" then.

Comment: (Well, I mean, you could place the button into an element that itself has a solid background. But that could easily collide with the background color of other ancestor elements then, I suppose - plus you'd effectively end up with a _solid_ background color for the button again, so you could rather calculate the appropriate solid color for the button itself to begin with then.)

Comment: @CBroe, In real app, the color are dynamic and hence I cannot give one particular color to disable.. In this example its like red shade but it may be green or blue etc.., And really we don't know what color exactly the box will have as border and based on that oly we make the disabled button color..

Comment: @CBroe, Kindly help me here without adding any new color, how can we achieve the things of making the border actually to look behind the disabled button.

Comment: _"In real app, the color are dynamic and hence I cannot give one particular color to disable"_ - but you are using SASS, so using the color manipulation functions this provides could probably be an option? Using opacity for a "disabled" look is a really bad idea, IMHO - you are already experiencing which problems that can bring, so I would not continue on that path.

Comment: @CBroe, Okay I understood but could you please provide me some startup solution from where I can start with considering the above example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
button::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(197, 218, 227,.5);
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
button {
    background-color: rgb(197, 218, 227);
    border-radius: 37px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 5px;
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    border: unset;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```